# What can be an owner?

Tags: rust, ownership

The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html) states:

> Each value in Rust has an *owner*

It does not explain what type of entity this owner is. Is it a programmer? a variable? A statement? A code block?

What is the precise definition of what type of entity can be a 'value owner'?

Comment: It's a variable or field. Basically, there needs to be some "thing" so that if that "thing" goes out of scope you know for sure the variable can be safely deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, owners are variables or fields; they are responsible for dropping the value owned. However, more surprisingly, even the program binary can be an owner too. As an example, that's the case for string literals:

```
let s = "Hello World";
```

The string literal above is stored in the program binary itself, `s` is just a reference to it. As such, its lifetime is `'static`, i.e., the literal lifespan corresponds to the program execution.

Answer (score 1):

As other people stated, owners are variables or fields.

I just wanted to add a practical example:

```rust
fn main() {
    // s is the owner of the string.
    let s: String = String::from("Hello!");

    // r is the owner of the reference, which in turn references s.
    // It can access the string, but does not own it.
    let r: &String = &s;

    // That means if we drop `s`, which owns the string, the string gets destroyed.
    drop(s);

    // Meaning `r` is now also forced to be dropped, because it does not own the
    // string, and would now be a dangling reference. The borrow checker prevents
    // dangling references, so this is a compilation error.
    println!("{}", r);
}
```

```
error[E0505]: cannot move out of `s` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:10:10
   |
7  |     let r: &String = &s;
   |                      -- borrow of `s` occurs here
...
10 |     drop(s);
   |          ^ move out of `s` occurs here
...
15 |     println!("{}", r);
   |                    - borrow later used here
```